# Understanding service processes

Tags: android, service

#### Edit to focus on the problem

This question seems hard to understand. Here the summary.
I apparently don't understand the real effects of `android:process`. Who can explain that to me?
I already tried things but still don't get it right. See text below for details, but the underlying problem is: what does this tag really do?

- What happens when different apps access a service that runs in "the app's process"? Can the same objects live in different processes if the service keeps running?
- Where should I notice differences in the tag's variations?

It doesn't help much to ask me what I saw and what I tried. I tried things and saw unexpected effects that don't match to what I read in the docs. To get along I need facts, no assumptions on my own.

### The original question

Apps can bind to my Android service. The service manages stuff that must be the same for all apps, and also if one app unbinds and binds again. The service lives a long time, I can ensure it with a foreground icon.
Now I can't get the meaning of `android:process`, lot of info is found all over the internet but it doesn't match to what I experience.

To examine that I log in the message handler and other places like onBind

- the service instance's hashcode
- the process ID
- the hashcode of a static object in the service class.

Then I bind to my service from an external app. It produces

- for each bind a new service instance hashcode
- the same pid for all binds
- the same static object's hashcode

#### Question 1

This tells me the service process stays alive between bindings but it always creates a new service instance. Am I right with this assumption?

#### Question 2

The funny part is, the above said is true if I specify no `android:process`, or a process starting with colon or a process starting with lowercase character, which actually is documented to have different effects.
Shouldn't I get different process IDs with a colon? What am I understanding wrong?

What `andorid:process` should I specify best? I assume the one that starts lowercase because this runs in a global process, but I don't see the difference in my test.

#### Question 3

As I need the internal objects preserved, is it ok to keep a static / singleton object that is used by all service instances and synchronizes accesses to this object internally?

#### Question 4

I tested what happens when I start an activity in the same apk that creates a service instance. When an external app binds to my service, the static object's hashcode for the activity's service instance and the service instances created on external bind is the same if there is no `android:process` specified.
If I specify a name (with or without colon) these hashes are different.

To me this means that without a process name there is one only process creating all service instances, so the static object is created only once. With a give process name the activity and the service run in different processes. Am I right if I explain this by the explicit process name in the service's manifest section that forces the service part of my apk to be in a separate process?

So if I also want the activity to access the same data, I better don't specify any process name in the manifest? How does this comply to the global process that I get with a name starting with a lowercase letter?

#### Edit: Hopefully this makes clearer what I want.

I have a service that administrates some data. It's accessed by apps, basically one app but multiple apps must be possible. This app /apps can be active or not, it comes... it goes ... and always binds to the service.
Each binding creates a new service instance. But what I need is access to the same underlying class. Now I asked how to achieve this best. A singleton class used by every bound service?
To do that I need to make sure that all bindings come into the same process. (right? maybe this is already wrong)
Examination of the android:process tag raised some more questions, see above. So I'd be glad to get more insight into this topic. No assuming but knowing and understanding would help me a lot.

I bind to the service, then use Messenger to exchange messages with the service. There is no AIDL or other means to directly call methods in the service.

Comment: I did :-) that's where the insights came that I told with "for each binding" and so on. This shows me what happens but doesn't explain why, or how the android:process tag affects this behaviour. (Edit to make that clearer)

Comment: @Kling Klang I can't understand why you removed "Android" from the title. If you were aware of the subject you'd know that an Android service is something very different from other kinds of service that one might think of. We should keep clear what this question is talking about.

Comment: Because **tags** must stay in the **tag area** only, not in the **title**

Comment: @pskink according to my tests it's the same. But the docs read as if it should be different. So this is my big gap in understanding :-)

Comment: Whereever android:process is documented. I guess I simply don't understand that as I should. I mean I should see a difference for different settings. But where? Then coming back to my task, being in the same process surely is a precondition to share data, but what else do I need to make that work?

Comment: There are a couple of questions above. What is unclear to you? I tested the android:process tag but I don't see the difference it makes and I'm asking for an explanation.

Comment: I edited my post, hope that helps. The basic questioin is how to ensure that all bindings can access the same data, how to achieve this and where my lack of understanding is with the android:process tag.

Comment: Different other apps. This is the central reason to ask what the whole process thing is about. I think  "service runs in app's process" is useless for me because one data structure can't be accesses from within different processes at the same time? At least I guessed that from the description, but my test showed that the static object and the process (pid) were identical for all three possibilities to set or not set android:process, so I'm already out at this point. It would help me to get answers to my questions. What is unclear about them? Edit section was refined again.

Comment: To clarify this comment chain, obviously pskink decided to remove his comments and make this discussion kind of useless...